# Android: How to create an attribute of type ID reference (mimic behavior of View::nextFocusDown)

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a custom view of type A that needs a reference to another view of type B.

I would like to set the reference to B on the design screen of Android Studio, just like you would with the attribute `nextFocusLeft`. For example, with `nextFocusLeft`, when you click the *pick a resource* button on the attributes panel you get a list of valid IDs for other views in the layout.

This is what I have so far in my `values/attrs.xml` file:

```
    <declare-styleable name="AView">
        <attr name="bView" format="reference" />
    </declare-styleable>
```

Then, I declare my `AView` class as follows (Kotlin):

```
class AView(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : View(context, attrs) {

    private var bViewId: Int = -1

    @IdRes
    @InspectableProperty(name = "bView")
    fun bViewId() : Int {
        return cameraViewId
    }

    fun bViewId(@IdRes value : Int) {
        cameraViewId = value
    }
}
```

This makes the attribute appear in the design screen alright. However, when I click on the "*pick a resource*" button I get a list of *String* resources instead of the ID resources I want.

**What am I missing here? Why I don't get a list of ID's?**